# Issue starting WSO2 IS example playground2

Tags: java, wso2-identity-server

I have followed all the steps form the tutorial, but can't start the example. As I start the server and go to  `localhost:8080/playground2`/ I enter all the fields, then it redirects me to a page where I log in with my admin account and the when I go to `localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize` it gives me an exception [image]

when I check the server console, this is the error I see [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found what was the problem. I solved the issue by clearing all the browser cookies. Not quite sure why this happened, but this solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this looks like a known issue[1] which is fixed by now. You can get the latest updated pack with all the recent fixes using WSO2 Update Manager. Follow this [blog](http://wso2.com/blogs/thesource/2016/09/keep-your-wso2-products-up-to-date-with-wum/) on step by step instructions to get an updated IS 5.3.0 pack.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-5581